# Laravel Eloquent Model with multiple IDs

Tags: laravel

I will have a table that is full of information that involves other tables (relations). Most of the information in this table will only have the ID's of the referencing related table. If I were to use "products" as an example for this table it may look like this for some of the columns:

```
id  |  name  |  type_id  |  price_id  |  location_id  |  sale_id
----------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |  prod1 |     1     |      1     |       2       |     4
 2  |  prod2 |     2     |      1     |       1       |     1
 3  |  prod3 |     3     |      2     |       6       |     2
 4  |  prod4 |     1     |      2     |       3       |     4
```

I'm trying to take this "products" table and dump it out into a list. I would need to look up all of the items in these columns as I dump it out (the relation). I know how to do belongsToMany and hasMany, but I'm not sure how I can do this in one shot with an Eloquent model if I have a "products" model? Should I just make the products table just a pivot table? Can I do it with an Eloquent model or should I use query builder directly? I think if I were to use withPivot it would return the extra columns but the raw ID value from the column. I would need the value lookup from their respective table (the relation).

Tried something like this:

```
public function productItems(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot(["type_id","price_id",...]);
}
```

Comment: what you have tried? how do your models looked like? have you checked [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) in laravel?

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: err, could you post your `Product` model?? also, where is this `productItems()` in? is the table above represent `Product` or something else?

Comment: After reading your question 2 times, I don't understand what do you want. But I think you can find out about EAV model to design product table structure more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @BagusTesa, you should eager load your relations:

```
$products = Product::with(['type', 'price', 'location'])->get();
```

That will query for the related models allowing you to access them as model properties:

```
foreach ($products as $product){
    // $product->type;
    // $product->price;
    // $product->location;
}
```

Comment: To answer above as well, the public function productItems() would be under a "stores" model. Where I'm getting a list of products for a particular store.  If I do that eager loading, I'm assuming I'd have to have models for each of those columns to be looked up? So for the Products model I'd have relation functions for each type, price, location, etc whatever it may be... belongsToMany, belongsTo, etc.

Comment: Yes for eloquent to establish the relationship you would need a model representing type, price, location, etc with the appropriate relation function on the product model and the inverse of each on the other models connecting back to product.

Comment: Yes I believe I got it now. I will code it out and test. I kept thinking pivot pivot pivot and completely forgot about eager loading. I'd probably want to do that anyway with a list that can be fairly large.